# Why php group $_FILES values in order of name, type instead of input filedname?

Tags: php, file

I'm getting the following array when I upload array of files.

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        ["name"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
        } 
        ["type"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
        ...
    } 
}
```

What is reason (technical reason or any benefits) behind the array received in the above format instead of the following ?

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        [0]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
            ...
        }, 
        [1]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html" 
            ...
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: from where you getting this array like can u please provide little more information

Comment: @Prateik: [The normal way.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the basic way of how $_FILES provides array now if you want to convert that into the formate you specified i found the code form the  [link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

A nice trick to reorder the $_FILES array when you use a input name as array is:

```
<?php 
    function diverse_array($vector) { 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($vector as $key1 => $value1) 
            foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) 
                $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2; 
                return $result; 
    } 
?>
```

will transform this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        ["name"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
        } 
        ["type"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

into:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        [0]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
        }, 
        [1]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

just do:

```
<?php $upload = diverse_array($_FILES["upload"]); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I appreciate it. I was looking the benefits or the reason behind this pattern. Because of this pattern many programmers have to diverse this array eg: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html Code in my question is taken from the same php page you mentioned :-)